# send mail with gmail in symfony

Tags: symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

I want to send emails with the swiftmailer and gmail in a symfony 3.4 project, but I succeeded in local but not in prod.

parameters.yml

```
database_host: server_bdd_ovh
database_port:
database_name: trexfastjjtrex
database_user: database uder
database_password: password database
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_port: 587
mailer_user: address@gmail.com
mailer_password: password
mailer_prod_encryption: tls
administrateur_contact_mail: address@gmail.com
webmaster_contact_mail: address@gmail.com
payee_email: null
```

config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    auth_mode: "%mailer_auth_mode%"
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    port:      "%mailer_port%"
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
```

Locally it works but not in prod are there configurations to do
Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to allow access from less secure apps via this link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps. May be the local app had the access and the hosted app did not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that I did it so that's not the problem.